# While doing Data Wrangling on DataFrame, what does this error means?

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, seaborn

> Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing label will raise KeyError in the future, you can use .reindex() as an alternative.

`pokemon` is a csv file loaded.

[image]